# Two identity columns

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I am using ORMlite and I wonder if it is possible to have multiple identity columns in one table.

I have a table with two specific columns among others: ID and Number. I want ORMlite only to update the row if ID and Number are the same, otherwise it should create a new row.  I am using the Method `createOrUpdate`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read through this article and the ORMLite documentation;
[Multiple primary keys - ORMlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469562/multiple-primary-keys-ormlite)

I'm not 100% sure on the answer by this. `uniqueCombo = true`  seems to be a good guess, but i'm not sure if things such as Update and Delete still work then. You'd have to test it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for that link, totally missed it. I tried uniqueCombo before but it does not work for my problem.

Answer (score 2):

> I want ORMlite only to update the row if ID and Number are the same, otherwise it should create a new row (I am using the Method createOrUpdate).

Yeah, you are not going to be able to use `createOrUpdate(...)` however you should be able to add your own DAO method to simulate it quite nicely.  If `ID` is not going to be unique then you'll need to create another ID field as the identity and use your `ID` as just another field, possible with a `uniqueCombo` restriction.

```
@DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
private int uniqueId;
// not the id field because it is not unique
@DatabaseField
private int id;
@DatabaseField
private int number;
```

In your DAO class, override the `BaseDaoImpl` class and override the `createOrUpdate(...)` method.  It should do something like:

```
public CreateOrUpdateStatus createOrUpdate(Foo data) throws SQLException {
    QueryBuilder<Foo, Integer> qb = queryBuilder();
    // NOTE: id here is not the identity field
    qb.where().eq("id", data.id).and().eq("number", data.number);
    Foo existing = qb.queryForFirst();
    if (existing == null) {
        int numRows = create(data);
        return new CreateOrUpdateStatus(true, false, numRows);
    } else {
        int numRows = update(data);
        return new CreateOrUpdateStatus(false, true, numRows);
    }
}
```

As an optimization, you could create that query beforehand using the `ThreadLocalSelectArg` arguments for the id and number args and then just set the args and run the query in the `createOrUpdate(...)` method.

Comment: In the `else` case, don't you have to assign the `uniqueId` field of the existing `Foo` entry to the `data` object before calling `update(data)`? Because otherwise, the Dao wouldn't know which row to update. Also, before calling `create(data)`, you'd have to make sure that the `uniqueId` field of the `data` item is not already existing in the database table.

Comment: I don't think so @saschoar.  In the else you know that `existing` has the same `id` and `number` as `data` because of the query.  This _should_ mean that the `uniqueId` is the same.  If it isn't then some data inconsistency has happened.

Comment: I know what you mean, @Gray, but when entering the `else{...}` case, it could still mean that the `uniqueId` field of `data` is not set: Think about a case where you get the `data` item from an API (that only returns the `id` and `number` fields, not your local `uniqueId` for that item) and you want save it in your database with `createOrUpdate()`. I'd say that case is quite common when you use ORMlite for syncing remote and local data.