# Ormlite Multiple PK on class I do not have control

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I have a class that I cannot change which has multiple @Id (annotated in JPA annotation) fields and some other annotations that ormlite does not support. So I am creating the table using java code to annotate the class.

However, without the ability to add an extra field to the class, the UniqueCombo trick mentioned in [Multiple primary keys - ORMlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469562/multiple-primary-keys-ormlite) does not work for me because for example:

```
class A {
  @Id
  int key1;

  @Id
  int key2;
}
```

with the following Java code to create ormlite table config:

```
DatabaseField f = new DatabaseField("key1");
f.setId(true);
f.setUniqueCombo(true);
fieldConfig.add(f);

f = new DatabaseField("key2");
f.setUniqueCombo(true);
fieldConfig.add(f);
```

if I set any of them as PK (setId(true)) then when the data are actually different, the DB will not be happy when I try to create another row with the same key. Are there any way to solve this problem without changing class A?

Answer (score 0):

No, ORMlite allows only one field as a primary key.