# Problems with multiple primary keys using ORMLITE

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I use the ORMLite Poco generator for my database.

The problem is that I have a table with multiple primary keys, and when I try to add any data into the database I get unique constraints.

I have read that I use @DatabaseField (uniqueCombo = true) but I have no idea where to add that. Please help me

This is my code in Poco class generator and all of the fields below are part of the primary key.

```
    tables["FieldLookupGroupFieldLookup"].Ignore = false;
tables["FieldLookupGroupFieldLookup"].ClassName = "CustomFieldGroupRelation";
tables["FieldLookupGroupFieldLookup"]["FieldLookupId"].PropertyName="CustomFieldValueId";
tables["FieldLookupGroupFieldLookup"]["ApplicationId"].PropertyName="CompanyId";
tables["FieldLookupGroupFieldLookup"]["FieldLookupGroupId"].PropertyName="GroupId";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use multiple primary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469562/how-to-use-multiple-primary-keys)

Answer (score 0):

OrmLite [does not support multiple Primary Keys](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#limitations).

Comment: So there is no way to get around this?  Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by it by adding new field for ID

[AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

See here

[Multiple primary keys - ORMlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469562/multiple-primary-keys-ormlite)