# How to implement multiple primary keys in ORMLite

Tags: java, ormlite, composite-primary-key

In my database there are many tables with double primary keys and even triples. Would I have a great request how to map such a table in ormlite in Java? For example: I have an Order and Product table, and a third table Order_Product, who join erlier mentioned two tables. In third table i have 2 master keys: order_id and product_id, and a normal field: quantity. I would be very grateful for explaining this problem (some examples). P.S. Sorry for my english.

I have read that i should use an attribute like uniqueCombo, useGetSet, but I do not know how to do it. And i don't know if i could use foreign annotation for these primary fields.

````java
``` def class Order:
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "Orders")
public class Order{

    public Order(){}

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private int id;

    @DatabaseField(columnName = "Date", canBeNull = false)
    private Date date;

    public int getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }

    public Date getDate() { return date; }
    public void setDate(Date date) { this.date = date; }
}
````

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "Products")
public class Product{

    public Product(){}

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private int id;

    @DatabaseField(columnName = "Name", canBeNull = false)
    private String name;

    public int getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
}
```

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "Order_Products")
public class Order_Product{

    public Order_Product(){}

    @DatabaseField(id = true, uniqueCombo=true)
    private int order_id;

    @DatabaseField(id = true, uniqueCombo=true)
    private int product_id;

    @DatabaseField(columnName = "Quantity", canBeNull = false)
    private int quantity;

    public int getOrder_id() { return order_id; }
    public void setOrder_id(int order_id) { this.order_id = order_id; }

    public int getProduct_id() { return product_id; }
    public void setProduct_id(int product_id) { this.product_id = product_id; }

    public int getQuantity() { return quantity; }
    public void setQuantity(int quantity) { this.quantity = quantity; }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use multiple primary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469562/how-to-use-multiple-primary-keys)

Comment: Thank you for answer.Yes, i duplicated, but i'm beginer in use Ormlite and these answers did not solve my problem. I would love to get a clearer and extended answer if possible.